# Spring-Data-JPA Hibernate: how to override/update a detached entity with the same ID?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have to override/update a set of existing entities mapped by a cascade `@OneToMany` relationship from another class.

I would like to avoid having to previously load the existing entities and then save them
for making them `attached` to the session.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_asset")
public class MyAsset  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myAsset",
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AssetComponent> components = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

---

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@SelectBeforeUpdate
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "asset_component")
public class AssetComponent {
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "model_id", nullable = false)
    private UUID modelID;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private MyAsset myAsset;
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public interface MyAssetRepository extends JpaRepository<MyAsset, Long> {}
```

---

Now, if I have an existing MyAsset with some existing components already in the DB, I cannot save the MyAsset directly:

```
MyAsset myAsset = new MyAsset();
myAsset.setComponents(Collections.singletonList(AssetComponent.builder()
        .id(UUID.fromString("b76d8a3b-2f0c-442a-bf50-58a19fce0fc9"))
        .modelID(UUID.fromString("22db9474-eeeb-4007-91a8-3e8bdfa9b83a"))
        .name("Component A")
        .type("Type A")
        .myAsset(myAsset)
    .build()));

myAssetRepository.save(myAsset);
```

because it gives me a stack of exceptions about the `duplicate key exception` with the `AssetComponent ID`:

- `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException`
- `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`
- `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`

How can I make the MyAsset & AssetComponent `@Repository` automatically merge the existing entities (if they have the same id) even if they have not been previously loaded from the DB?

**Update**

I created a GitHub repository to show you the minimum not working example: https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/Spring-Data-JPA-Testing

I slightly changed the entities' name to make them as much general as possible: `Container 1 --> N Item`

I also enabled as much debugging as possible (at least i think so. Let me know if I can show more debugging info) using these properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: test
    password: test
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.type: trace
```

This is the simple `@Test` I'm running:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ContainerRepositoryTests {
    @Autowired
    private ContainerRepository containerRepository;

    @Test
    public void testSaveContainer(){
        final UUID containerID = UUID.randomUUID();

        Container container = new Container();
        container.setId(containerID);

        Collection<Item> items = new HashSet<>();

        final UUID itemID = UUID.randomUUID();

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setId(itemID);
        item.setContainer(container);

        items.add(item);

        container.setItems(items);

        this.containerRepository.save(container);

        this.containerRepository.save(container);
    }
}
```

and it results in the following console output:

```
Hibernate: 


    drop table if exists container CASCADE 
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists container_items CASCADE 
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists item CASCADE 
Hibernate: 
    
    create table container (
       id binary(255) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    
    create table container_items (
       container_id binary(255) not null,
        items_id binary(255) not null
    )
Hibernate: 
    
    create table item (
       id binary(255) not null,
        container_id binary(255) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table container_items 
       add constraint UK_tjc4gid6ob0h8pqhc9f4s1u9k unique (items_id)
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table container_items 
       add constraint FK3jaf77lxfykpono42ak2pqh7p 
       foreign key (items_id) 
       references item
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table container_items 
       add constraint FKt1xy6gjb3c94t8ifnjp36hsol 
       foreign key (container_id) 
       references container
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table item 
       add constraint FK9b9sc6vhhyquxqbixmhqtx0g 
       foreign key (container_id) 
       references container
```

---

```
Hibernate: 
    /* load org.testing.spring.data.jpa.domain.Container */ select
        container0_.id as id1_0_1_,
        items1_.container_id as containe1_1_3_,
        item2_.id as items_id2_1_3_,
        item2_.id as id1_2_0_,
        item2_.container_id as containe2_2_0_ 
    from
        container container0_ 
    left outer join
        container_items items1_ 
            on container0_.id=items1_.container_id 
    left outer join
        item item2_ 
            on items1_.items_id=item2_.id 
    where
        container0_.id=?
2022-06-10 09:36:41.066 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [b8718f19-8a5c-480a-bcb4-a116a74a0fd0]
Hibernate: 
    /* load org.testing.spring.data.jpa.domain.Item */ select
        item0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        item0_.container_id as containe2_2_0_ 
    from
        item item0_ 
    where
        item0_.id=?
2022-06-10 09:36:41.100 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [63050373-8b6b-4fca-8ead-49319ee0c1bb]
Hibernate: 
    /* insert org.testing.spring.data.jpa.domain.Container
        */ insert 
        into
            container
            (id) 
        values
            (?)
2022-06-10 09:36:41.121 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [b8718f19-8a5c-480a-bcb4-a116a74a0fd0]
Hibernate: 
    /* insert org.testing.spring.data.jpa.domain.Item
        */ insert 
        into
            item
            (container_id, id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
2022-06-10 09:36:41.124 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [b8718f19-8a5c-480a-bcb4-a116a74a0fd0]
2022-06-10 09:36:41.125 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BINARY] - [63050373-8b6b-4fca-8ead-49319ee0c1bb]
Hibernate: 
    /* insert collection
        row org.testing.spring.data.jpa.domain.Container.items */ insert 
        into
            container_items
            (container_id, items_id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
2022-06-10 09:36:41.128 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [b8718f19-8a5c-480a-bcb4-a116a74a0fd0]
2022-06-10 09:36:41.128 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BINARY] - [63050373-8b6b-4fca-8ead-49319ee0c1bb]
Hibernate: 
    /* load org.testing.spring.data.jpa.domain.Container */ select
        container0_.id as id1_0_1_,
        items1_.container_id as containe1_1_3_,
        item2_.id as items_id2_1_3_,
        item2_.id as id1_2_0_,
        item2_.container_id as containe2_2_0_ 
    from
        container container0_ 
    left outer join
        container_items items1_ 
            on container0_.id=items1_.container_id 
    left outer join
        item item2_ 
            on items1_.items_id=item2_.id 
    where
        container0_.id=?
2022-06-10 09:36:41.134 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [b8718f19-8a5c-480a-bcb4-a116a74a0fd0]
Hibernate: 
    /* load org.testing.spring.data.jpa.domain.Item */ select
        item0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        item0_.container_id as containe2_2_0_ 
    from
        item item0_ 
    where
        item0_.id=?
2022-06-10 09:36:41.137 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [63050373-8b6b-4fca-8ead-49319ee0c1bb]
Hibernate: 
    /* insert org.testing.spring.data.jpa.domain.Container
        */ insert 
        into
            container
            (id) 
        values
            (?)
2022-06-10 09:36:41.138 TRACE 12924 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [b8718f19-8a5c-480a-bcb4-a116a74a0fd0]
2022-06-10 09:36:41.141  WARN 12924 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2022-06-10 09:36:41.142 ERROR 12924 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_8 ON PUBLIC.CONTAINER(ID) VALUES ( /* 1 */ CAST(X'b8718f198a5c480abcb4a116a74a0fd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' AS BINARY(255)) )"; SQL statement:
/* insert org.testing.spring.data.jpa [23505-212]
2022-06-10 09:36:41.142  INFO 12924 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_8 ON PUBLIC.CONTAINER(ID) VALUES ( /* 1 */ CAST(X'b8718f198a5c480abcb4a116a74a0fd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' AS BINARY(255)) )"; SQL statement:
/* insert org.testing.spring.data.jpa [23505-212]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy111.save(Unknown Source)
    at org.testing.spring.data.jpa.repository.ContainerRepositoryTests.testSaveContainer(ContainerRepositoryTests.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_8 ON PUBLIC.CONTAINER(ID) VALUES ( /* 1 */ CAST(X'b8718f198a5c480abcb4a116a74a0fd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' AS BINARY(255)) )"; SQL statement:
/* insert org.testing.spring.data.jpa [23505-212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:508)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.index.Index.getDuplicateKeyException(Index.java:525)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.checkUnique(MVSecondaryIndex.java:223)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.add(MVSecondaryIndex.java:184)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:519)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:174)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:135)
    at org.h2.command.dml.DataChangeStatement.update(DataChangeStatement.java:74)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:174)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:252)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:209)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 103 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate already does select by id before saving detached entity. But the problem is that hibernate can't find entity by uuid. I don't know exactly how it works (it is possible that the problem is in the DBMS), but you can fix it by adding `@Type` annotation:

```
@Entity
public class Container {
    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Spring Data JPA should already detect, that the entity is not new and should call `merge`.

You could make your entity implement `Persistable` which should fix the problem.

Alternatively, you could create a breakpoint in `SimpleJpaRepository.save(..)` and debug, why Spring Data JPA doesn't consider your entity new.

Comment: I implemented the `Persistable<UUID>` interface in the `AssetComponent` with `public boolean isNew() {return false; }` but it still throws the duplicate key exception.

Comment: Can you post the results of your debugging effort, the SQL executed, the full stack trace and the DDL of the table and constraint involved?

Comment: Sure, I just updated my question with a link to the MWE GitHub repository and the console output

Comment: does the problem persist, when you add a `flush` between the two `save` operations?

Comment: yes, same error.